# How to parameterize pyodbc identifiers in queries safely?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have written a small tool which migrates data from SQL Server to Postgres.

To make things work, I did it quick and dirty using string concats since I had a lot of other issues to solve and I did not want to bother with the SQL at the time. But now that everything is sorted out, I want to do things porperly in the SQL department.

The unsafe quick and dirty version :

```
import pyodbc
# this is the bad example DON'T do this
    def getDataFromTable(self,table):
        """
        Gets all data from the specified Table.
        table -- Table name as string
        """
        cursor = self.cursor
        SQL = f"""SELECT * FROM {table}""" ## DON'T do this
        cursor.execute(SQL)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        records = []
        for row in rows:
            records.append(list(row))
        return records
```

This works perfectly fine, but is a SQL injection waiting to happen.

I want to build something like this (I have omitted the unchanged parts):

```
...
cursor = self.cursor
SQL = f"""SELECT * FROM ?""" # Use parameters insted of string concats
cursor.execute(SQL, table) # pass parameters to the execute method.
rows = cursor.fetchall()
...
```

This looks nice an safe, but also does not work. Following error pops up :

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Die @P1-Tabellenvariable muss deklariert werden. (1087) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Anweisung(en) konnte(n) nicht vorbereitet werden. (8180)')

It's in German but roughly translates to: table variables must be declared, statement could not be prepared.

How can I pass a variable into the execute method to take the identifiers place safely?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a variable for table name in SQL Server. You can generate a string in python and then execute it.

```
table_name = 'table1' 
query = "Select * from %s" % table_name
```

Or you can use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames).

Comment: Hey thank you, i have tried this, but it does not work either, error changed though :


**pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')**